# Load a DropDownList in MVC with database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to load in a DropDownList the data from a column of a table in SQL, I'm using Entity Framework Database First for handle the database where I have a table called "Maquinas" and the column I want to show is called "UID", the code that I am Using is the following:

```
SistemaCajaConexion db = new SistemaCajaConexion();
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Pagos()
{
   var ListaDB = db.Maquinas.ToList();

   ViewBag.Lista = new SelectList(ListaDB, "UID");

   return View();
}
```

And the code of the `View()` is the following:

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("MiLista", ViewBag.Lista as SelectList)
</div>
```

I believe that all is good, but when I run instead of showing the data I have in the UID column, the following is shown:

System.Data.Entity.DinamicProxies.Maquinas_(some hexadecimal values)

Can someone help me on how I can solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You should pass as second parameter of SelecteList the property you need to show as text option of your dropdown list.

Comment: What do I pass in the first parameter? I believed than in the first parameter I had to pass the property that I need to show

Comment: The first parameter is the list, the second is used as value attribute, the third need to be passed if you want to show the correct text.

Comment: `SelectList(ListaDB, "UID", "here_you_put_the_name_of_property_you_need_to_show")`

Comment: I did needed to pass the third parameter, now it works fine, thank you CodeNotFound

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your SelectList initialization with following:

```
ViewBag.Lista = new SelectList(ListaDB, "UID", "UID");
```